# PHP issue using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

Hello I have the following code in PHP:

```
        $str1 = "A charge of
<b>$3.03</b>
including fees of
<b>$1.03</b>
and
<b>$1.00</b>
on 02/17/2017";

        $message = '<p><b>Your payment will be scheduled as below:</b></p><p id=\'firstPaymentCC\'>A charge of <b id=\'firstPaymentCCB\'>$2.03</b> including a fee of <b>$1.03</b> on 02/17/2017</p><p>A charge of <b id=\'firstPaymentCCB\'>$2.03</b> including a fee of <b>$1.03</b> on 02/24/2017</p><p>A charge of <b id=\'firstPaymentCCB\'>$2.03</b> including a fee of <b>$1.03</b> on 03/03/2017</p><p>A charge of <b id=\'firstPaymentCCB\'>$2.03</b> including a fee of <b>$1.03</b> on 03/10/2017</p>';

        echo preg_replace("/<p id='firstPaymentCC'>[\s\S]+?<\/p>/", $str1, $message);
```

What I want to do is to extract text between the 2 delimiters `<p id='firstPaymentCC'> and </p>` in the variable `$message` and replace it with the content of the variable `$str1`.

The result I'm getting is : Your payment will be scheduled as below:
A charge of .03 including fees of .03 and .00 on 02/17/2017

A charge of $2.03 including a fee of $1.03 on 02/24/2017

A charge of $2.03 including a fee of $1.03 on 03/03/2017

A charge of $2.03 including a fee of $1.03 on 03/10/2017

why there is .03 and .00 while it should be $1.03 and $1.00 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$str1` contains a *replacement pattern*.

In a replacement pattern, `$` + number defines a *backreference*.

If you do not want to define a backreference, escape the dollar symbol:

```
$str1 = "A charge of
<b>\\\$3.03</b>
including fees of
<b>\\\$1.03</b>
and
<b>\\\$1.00</b>
on 02/17/2017";
```

Note: since the string is defined with a double quoted string literal, to define a `$` symbol it needs to be escaped (`"\$"`), and to define a literal backslash (that will escape the literal dollar symbol) two backslashes are required (`"\\"`). See more about [PHP string literals here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Answer (score -1):

$ references the matched contents for pairs of brackets used in the pattern - $1 matching the first set and $2 matching the second set etc.

you can use this like so:

`echo preg_replace('/([0-9]+):([0-9]+)/','$1 hours and $2 mins','12:23');`

This would output: `12 hours and 23 mins`

If you just want to replace with an actual dollar symbol - you must escape with a slash:

```
$str1 = "A charge of
<b>\\$3.03</b>
including fees of
<b>\\$1.03</b>
and
<b>\\$1.00</b>
on 02/17/2017";
```

Note that you have to use double slashes.

Some more useful info here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html